# How I get only one value when I execute this sql query?

Tags: c#, sql

I am working with the table where i testing a query.

I have 3 columns where everyone have their own price.

I want when I select a specific column value then it show me only that column price not other two column.

```sql
select Small_price,Medium_price,Large_price
from New_Item
where Sub_Category='Sub' or Small_price='' or  Medium_price='' or Large_price='300'
```

In this query when I enter `large_price ='300'` I want when I execute it, it only show me column of `large_price` not other two of `medium_price` and `small_price`.

Anyone here to help?

Comment: Have you tried to write only `select Large_price` ?

Comment: you need to google `Dynamic query`.

Comment: at that time i am tesing i can enter large_price it will give me large_price but when i enter these values with textbox in code then i will give me error

Comment: @harshil I don't see how that is even vaguely related

Comment: @FazalAbbas perhaps the problem is with the code for the textbox. Can you show us that?

Comment: simply i want the price which i will enter it show me only that column

Comment: Does `nvl(small_price, nvl(medium_price, large_price))` work for you? Also, please specify your dbms

Comment: @MarcGravell He wants to select different columns based on the different conditions he uses in `Where` clause. That's dynamic query, isn't it?

Comment: Specify the SQL dialect or the RDBMS used.

Comment: @FazalAbbas You say you want only one column... but don't you want to say that you want to obtain as result a single row, for a single column, ie a single value? And are you sure your condition tests are correct? Also do you want to display one unique value in the label, or be able to navigate through the rows of the result and display one cell in the label, using previous and next buttons for example?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand the question but you can write any SQL query by specifying only the column you want for the result set:

```sql
select Large_price
from New_Item
where Sub_Category='Sub' or Small_price='' or  Medium_price='' or Large_price='300'
```

But perhaps you want to dynamiccaly generate a query or do a thing you may explain better in the question.

In case of you start in SQL, I hope this tutorial can help you to enjoy doing queries:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE..WHEN` statement to read specific column depends of your input parameter. Here, I am assuming you have three different parameters passing to this SQL, one for each price type. However, only one of these three parameters would be holding value at any given point in time.

```
select case when p_small_price is not null then , Small_price
when p_medium_price is not null then Medium_price
when p_large_price is not null then Large_price end as final_price
from New_Item
where Sub_Category='Sub' 
and (Small_price= p_small_price or  Medium_price= p_medium_price or Large_price= p_high_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `declare` and `set`.  It makes a variable so that your `where` and `select` can be the same value as needed.

```
DECLARE @pricetype

SET @pricetype = 'large'
```

Then use `@pricetype` in the `select` and `where` section.

Comment: Simply i want the column which value i passed then i will show as a result .but these method not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The query as you have it does not seem very sensible to me. I cannot imagine the business logic where you would want all records with all of these OR conditions structured like this.  You will get many different values of your three columns and I’m not sure about the semantics of the result.

For example, all you know about a result row that has a Large_price <> 300 is that one of the other prices = ‘’ or Sub_Category is ‘’. I’m not sure how that could be useful.

Perhaps I misunderstand or perhaps the query conditions are not what you really want.